# sed creates duplicate line instead of replacing existing line

Tags: bash, text, replace, sed

I have a file (foo.txt) containing the following:

```
some-text 0
```

I use the following sed-command to replace the 0 with a 1:

```
search_text="some-text";
sed "s/${search_text} 0/${search_text} 1/" -i foo.txt;
```

This results in foo.txt containing:

```
some-text 0
some-text 1
```

How can I get it to replace the found line instead of appending a new line?

It occurs with GNU sed version 4.2.1 on SL06.

Comment: Does your line finish with a carriage return? The only explanation I can think of is the undefined behaviour when the line is not complete. Depends on your environment and tool versions.

Comment: Havin a CR/NL doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Seems to work here. Maybe the actual 'some-text' contains some `sed` commands?

Comment: In this case it contains "adm-console-enabled". Doesn't seem to conflict with anything?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be reproducible. Do you get the same behaviour on your system if you use the example in the question?

Comment: It seems to be related to line-ending weirdness, a freshly created file from OSX doesn't have the issue, a file from Windows does.

Comment: Try using `dos2unix foo.txt` before using sed on the file

Comment: i have a similar problem. I do the desired change , but the row is duplicated. like "sed -i 's/(callback,/(on_message_callback=callback,/gp" . The replace happens but there are 2 rows in the end

Answer (score 0):

If you like to try `awk`

```
awk '/some-text/ {$2=1} 1' file
```

Comment: This gives me the same behaviour. Also an added line with the correct value instead of replacing the existing value.

Comment: This do what you asked for. Search for `some-text`, then set value to  `1` and print all. You can do like this to search for if its `0` `awk '/some-text/ {$2=1} 1' file > tmp && mv tmp file` to update original file.

Answer (score 0):

do you try

```
search_text='some-text'
sed -e "s/\(${search_text}\) 0/\1 1/" -i foo.txt
```

using group pattern instead of twice the search_text

which shell are you using (cause i see `;` like `c` end of line not often used on several line in shell) ?